# Is this proof correct about compact sets inside open sets?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, proof-verification

I've been solving the following problem: "If $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $C\subset U$ is compact, show that there is a compact set $D$ such that $C\subset \operatorname{int}(D)$ and $D\subset U$".

My proof was as follows: since $C\subset U$, then for every point $a\in C$ there is an open rectangle $R(a)\subset U$. If we pick $\mathcal{O}=\{R(a) : a\in C\}$, then $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of $C$. We know that we can choose each $R(a)$ so small so that $\overline{R(a)}\subset U$, so we admit we have done so when building $\mathcal{O}$.

Because of compactness of $C$ we know that it admits a finite subcover, which we will call $\mathcal{O}'=\{R(a_i) : a_i \in C , i\in I_k\}$ where we have $I_k=\{1,\dots,k\}$. In that case, consider the collection of all closures $\{\overline{R(a_i)} : i \in I_k\}$, we know that each $\overline{R(a_i)}\subset U$ and hence if we set

$$D=\bigcup_{i=1}^k \overline{R(a_i)},$$

it's clear that $D\subset U$. Moreover, $D$ is compact, because it's a finite union of compact subsets. Also, we have the relation

$$\operatorname{int}(D)=\bigcup_{i=1}^k R(a_i),$$

and hence, because $\mathcal{O}'$ is an open cover of $C$ we've found a compact set $D\subset U$ such that $C\subset \operatorname{int}(D)$.

Is this proof ok? I don't know if it's fine, so I thought in asking here. I'm mainly in doubt about shrinking the set so that it's closure remains inside $U$. I know that's possible, however I felt confused if I could simply state that or if I needed to prove that.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, you should immediately say that you choose $R(a)$ so that $\overline{R(a)} \subset U$. Then there's one glitch, you don't necessarily have $\operatorname{int}(D) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k R(a_i)$, you have $\supset$, and the inclusion can be strict (imagine you choose two rectangles with a common side); it doesn't hurt, of course, if that happens. Apart from these points, fine.